# Truncate WordPress post content without losing HTML formatting

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress theme where I need to truncate the post at a certain number of words. I understand how to use `the_excerpt()`, however this strips out all the paragraph breaks, links, etc. which is NOT the desired effect. I tried using jQuery Succinct and applying that to `the_content()` -- that maintained the formatting, but it cut off in the middle of a paragraph so I had an open `<p>` that then broke the rest of the layout. The client does not want to use the option to manually insert a "more" tag into the post.

Is there a way I can do this either via PHP or jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create your own excerpt function. I have written one that keeps all html tags in tact and also cut the excerpt at the end of a sentence just after the chosen amount of words.

You need to remove the original excerpt filter first and add your new one. Add this to your functions.php

```
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

Now add this below

```
function pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($pietergoosen_excerpt) {
    global $post;
    $raw_excerpt = $pietergoosen_excerpt;
        if ( '' == $pietergoosen_excerpt ) {

            $pietergoosen_excerpt = get_the_content('');
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $pietergoosen_excerpt );
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $pietergoosen_excerpt);
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $pietergoosen_excerpt);

            //Set the excerpt word count and only break after sentence is complete.
                $excerpt_word_count = 75;
                $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 
                $tokens = array();
                $excerptOutput = '';
                $count = 0;

                // Divide the string into tokens; HTML tags, or words, followed by any whitespace
                preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+>|[^<>\s]+)\s*/u', $pietergoosen_excerpt, $tokens);

                foreach ($tokens[0] as $token) { 

                    if ($count >= $excerpt_word_count && preg_match('/[\?\.\!]\s*$/uS', $token)) { 
                    // Limit reached, continue until ? . or ! occur at the end
                        $excerptOutput .= trim($token);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Add words to complete sentence
                    $count++;

                    // Append what's left of the token
                    $excerptOutput .= $token;
                }

            $pietergoosen_excerpt = trim(force_balance_tags($excerptOutput));

                $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
                $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 

                $pos = strrpos($pietergoosen_excerpt, '</');
                if ($pos !== false)
                // Inside last HTML tag
                $pietergoosen_excerpt = substr_replace($pietergoosen_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0);
                else
                // After the content
                $pietergoosen_excerpt .= $excerpt_end;

            return $pietergoosen_excerpt;   

        }
        return apply_filters('pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $pietergoosen_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if it is ok to comment on older post but is it possible to adjust the code so that it won't end if a dot is just after the year? We often have something like "Something something 1976. something something."

Comment: Also, sorry if I bother :) , but the excerpt won't work if a image is placed in the beginning of the post. For example, the result I get for those kind of posts is "img class=”alignnone size-full wp-image-8511″ src=”http://www."